# If I change queryData, I have issue: The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I just got acquainted with Gatsby and I need some help. I get data from query in Header component.
I need to remove "Pages" from Navigation menu, but when I try remove data, have an issue like on the third screenshot. And I can't find anything that could make "Pages" mandatory

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGX4U.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrXiV.png)
( https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpHuy.png)]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1):

step-1)  npm uninstall gatsby,
step-2) rm -rf node_modules,
step-3) add "gatsby": "2.23.3", to dependencies in package.json,
step-4) npm install,
step-5) gatsby develop

Then I updated each of the other outdated packages without error.

This may help you.